# changing ng-repeat generated class on click

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a menu generated from a controller, and I want to add a class on the appropriate menu item when I'm at a certain url (I use ngRoutes). The menu is generated from a `$scope.menu` object, so I thought I'd just add a style property to it, which I'd update upon clicking the link.

Now I'm stuck, because I need to loop trough the whole object every time the link is clicked, set all style properties to `idle`, and then set the clicked anchor's property to `highlighted`.

With jQuery I guess I'd use `$(this)`, but I don't know how to do it with angular.

my html:

```
<div class="header" ng-controller="NavbarController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="link in menu" class="{{link.style}}"><a ng-href="{{link.href}}">{{link.item}}</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

the controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularApp')
    .controller('NavbarController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.menu = [
            {
                item: 'articles',
                href: '#/articles',
                style: 'highlighted'
            },
            {
                item: 'sites',
                href: '#/sites',
                style: 'idle'
            },
            {
                item: 'contact',
                href: '#/contact',
                style: 'idle'
            },
            {
                item: 'forum',
                href: '#/forum',
                style: 'idle'
            },
            {
                item: 'account reviews',
                href: '#/account_reviews',
                style: 'idle'
            },
            {
                item: 'login',
                href: '#/login',
                style: 'idle'
            }
        ]; // end $scope.menu
        $scope.setMenuStlye = function() {
            for(x=0; x<$scope.menu.length; x++) {

            }
        }
    });
```

If there is a good alternative for doing this that I haven't thought of which uses angular, html or css please let me know. I am new to angularJS and improvising.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/712538pg/1/)

```
<li ng-repeat="link in menu" ng-class="menuClass(link.item)"><a ng-href="{{link.href}}">{{link.item}}</a>

$scope.menuClass = function (page) {

        var current = window.location.hash.substring(1).replace("/", "");
        console.log(current)
        return page === current ? "active" : "";
    };
```

You may pass the desired class as function parameters into the helper function.
One way or another I would highly suggest start using [UI Router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router) as it provides this functionality out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ngClass`:

```
<li ng-repeat="link in menu" ng-class="{highlighted: url === link.item}"><a ng-href="{{link.href}}">{{link.item}}</a></li>
```

And in your controller you have to grab the url via `window.location.hash` and then compare it to `link.item`:

```
.controller('NavbarController', function ($scope) {

  $scope.url = window.location.hash.substring(2);

}
```

Comment: this returns an error `"Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ':' is an unexpected token at column 12 of the expression [highlighted:url === link.item] starting at [:url === link.item].` . You are also using single curly braces instead of double ones on ng-class.

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič Ng-class doesn't use double braces. Were you using double ones? Because that might be what's causing the error.

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič Updated answer, you have to include substring in your controller as well to get the raw hash string. Also make sure you have a space after the semicolon. Might throw things off not having it.